# Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found when trying to add account using brownie on Linux

Tags: python, solidity, windows-subsystem-for-linux, brownie

I am trying to add an Ethereum account using Brownie. It is working if I add the private key hardcoded, but I get the following error if I try to use the environment variable (I am using Ubuntu on WSL):

> Running 'scripts/advancedCollectable/deploy_advanced.py::main'...
> File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
> return_value, frame = run(   File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 103, in run
> return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)   File "./scripts/advancedCollectable/deploy_advanced.py", line 4, in main
> dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])   File "brownie/network/account.py", line 142, in add
> w3account = web3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)   File "eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
> return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)   File "eth_account/account.py", line 250, in from_key
> key = self._parsePrivateKey(private_key)   File "eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
> return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)   File "eth_account/account.py", line 775, in _parsePrivateKey
> return self._keys.PrivateKey(HexBytes(key))   File "hexbytes/main.py", line 23, in **new**
> bytesval = to_bytes(val)   File "hexbytes/_utils.py", line 17, in to_bytes
> return hexstr_to_bytes(val)   File "hexbytes/_utils.py", line 50, in hexstr_to_bytes
> return binascii.unhexlify(ascii_hex) Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found Terminating local RPC client...

When I execute it with the private key hardcoded I get the following output (the expected one):

> LAPTOP:/mnt/c/Users/pedro/study/2022/Aplicação da proposta _
> NFT/contrato_nft$ brownie run
> scripts/advancedCollectable/deploy_advanced.py Brownie v1.18.1 -
> Python development framework for Ethereum
>
> ContratoNftProject is the active project.
>
> Launching 'ganache-cli --chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse true
> --server.port 8545 --miner.blockGasLimit 12000000 --wallet.totalAccounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --wallet.mnemonic brownie'...
>
> Running 'scripts/advancedCollectable/deploy_advanced.py::main'...
> development Terminating local RPC client...
> alucard86@LAPTOP-EV5UN7EH:/mnt/c/Users/pedro/study/2022/Aplicação da
> proposta _ NFT/contrato_nft$

Below is the code I am using. **I have changed two numbers from the private key**

Using the environment variable (execution results in the mentioned error):

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config

def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(network.show_active())
```

.env file:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=fdb0ee33d87a414d57244c1eb5df7b3cd15a69c3041214584e4eb2d2b220e2ef
```

Tryed with '' and "" too (get the same error):

```
export PRIVATE_KEY='fdb0ee33d87a414d57244c1eb5df7b3cd15a69c3041214584e4eb2d2b220e2ef'

export PRIVATE_KEY="fdb0ee33d87a414d57244c1eb5df7b3cd15a69c3041214584e4eb2d2b220e2ef"
```

brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Check env variable:

```
echo $PRIVATE_KEY
fdb0ee33d87a414d57244c1eb5df7b3cd15a69c3041214584e4eb2d2b220e2ef
```

**I have tried the private key with 0x at the begging of the string too, but I get the same error.**

Hardcoded private key script (execution is fine):

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config

def main():
    dev = accounts.add('fdb0ee33d87a414d57244c1eb5df7b3cd15a69c3041214584e4eb2d2b220e2ef')
    print(network.show_active())
```

When I run the code:

```
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible, accounts, network, config

def main():
    dev = accounts.add('fdb0ee33d87a414d57244c1eb5df7b3cd15a69c3041214584e4eb2d2b220e2ef')
    print(network.show_active())
    publish_source = False
    print(config['wallets']['from_key'])
```

I get the output:

> Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum
>
> ContratoNftProject is the active project.
>
> Launching 'ganache-cli --chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse true
> --server.port 8545 --miner.blockGasLimit 12000000 --wallet.totalAccounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --wallet.mnemonic brownie'...
>
> Running 'scripts/advancedCollectable/deploy_advanced.py::main'...
> development
> 0xfdb0ee33d87a414d57244c1eb5df7b3cd15a69c3041214584e4eb2d2b220e2ef
> Terminating local RPC client...

I have to make it work using the env variable. What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: Don't quote the key - i.e., *export PRIVATE_KEY=fbd0...*

Comment: As I said in the question: I did not quote the key in one of my attempts. Get the same error with or without quotes.

Comment: Try printing the value you get from the config file

Comment: I have just printed the value of config['wallets']['from_key'] and updated the question with this information.

Comment: **It prints the private key correctly.

Comment: After your latest edit we see that the key is prefixed with 0x

Comment: As I said in the question... I tried with 0x and without it. Same error for both.

Comment: I had shut down my computer and when I´ve turned it on, the app started to work. It was something wrong with the Operational System.